# How do I start bash in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, bash

I have a bash script that I need to execute. It seems that I can't run in in my terminal because it has a slightly different syntax.

I could run the first file like `bash ./configure` but it produces a makefile that I can not use. If I try `bash make` it tells me that it can't execute make.

How do I run this make file in bash?

I tried `cd /usr/bin  ./bash` but it tells me that it can't find bash.

So how do I start bash?

Comment: If you're trying to build a software from source, you should enter `./configure` (without `bash` in front) followed by `make`. Do you have `make` installed? it's probably in the `build-essential` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the command "bash" this will open an interactive bash terminal and then use it like the normal terminal and when you are done use the command "exit" to go back to your regular terminal.

Comment: nothing opens if I type "bash" :(

Comment: it won't look like its opened anything. try typing "ps -p $$" this should say that you are now using bash

Comment: no it still tries to use sh, if I use bash and then use make I get this "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"

Comment: This may be the problem, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh  there is some troubleshooting. i.e change the SHELL variable in the make file to /bin/bash